# Using dynamic object filter

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access names of all the students having marks 100.

```
def get_names(request):
    students = Result.objects.filter(marks=100)
    student_name = []
    for x in students:
        student_name.append(x.student)
    for x in student_name:
        print (x.name)
    return render(request, 'exam/index.html', {'names': student_name})
```

When I run this view, **'Student has no attribute '__getitem__''** is displayed on the line print(x.name). 
I read something about dynamic object filter but cannot figure it out in this case.

Model structure

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stream = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Result(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be helping yourself if you used more informative variable names, instead of seemingly going out of your way to come up with confusing ones. In your code snippet:

```
def get_names(request):
    results = Result.objects.filter(marks=100)
    students = []
    for result in results:
        students.append(result.student)
    for student in students:
        print(student.name)
    return render(request, 'exam/index.html', {'names': student_name})
```

That said, I don't understand where your `Student has no attribute '__getitem__'` is coming from, or why it is being printed and not raising an exception. `__getitem__` is for accessing items of sequences with integer or slice keys, and you don't seem to be doing that anywhere. From the models you presented here, `x` (or `student` in my code) should be a `Student` instance, and doing `print(x.name)` should work.

In any case, you could do this in a much simpler way:

```
def get_names(request)
    students = Student.objects.filter(result__marks=100).distinct()
    return render(request, 'exam/index.html', {'students': students})
```

Then you can iterate `students` in the template and acess `student.name`. If you just want to pass a list of names to the template, you could use `values_list('name', flat=True)` in the query.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I'll modify the variable names. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the student name

```
for x in students:
    print(x.student.name)
    student_name.append(x.student)
```

Comment: My main objective is to pass the list of names to a web page. But when the above mentioned error occurred, I added few extra lines to print the list on Python console.